# How to get last value of a column in PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The question is very trivial but I am completely new in the world of PySpark and I am facing a lot of problems even with easy tasks.

Suppose we have a dataframe df with a column A.

I want to create another dataframe that contains only one column with the last value of A (by last value here I mean the really record at the bottom of columnn A).

I have already tried something like

`df["A"][-1]` but I get error.

Please, I would like to have a solution for both Python code in PySpark and Pyspark Sql if possible.

Comment: Spark dataframes are not ordered. You have to define what "last" means somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be carefull with your ordering because in pyspark, DataFrame are not ordered by default. It means that `df.take(1)` might not always return the same value.

This post is very clear about that. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-16207

2 solutions:

1. Pick any random value from the column -> `take(1)` is fine
2. You have some kind of order and then you can use `sort` function and the `asc` parameter to reverse the sorting.

Comment: ok thanks, but a little more in general, what about the limit(1) function? Will it give me always the first record or even this will produce every time a different value?

Comment: @WorkBench `limit` will not always give the same record *unless* you specify a deterministic `order by`

Comment: My experience would say most of the time `take(1)` returns the same value unless you parallelize the computation. Then it is much more random and depend on the number of parallel cores you put. If you always want a specific value, you must order you dataframe at some point.